# html required attribute is not working with readonly

Tags: html, requiredfieldvalidator

```
<form action="check_rooms1.php" method="post"  name="search_room" class="form" >
        <p>


          <label for="checkin">Check in date</label>

          <input name="checkin" type="text" id="checkin"  placeholder="click to enter" readonly required>
         </p>
        <p>
          <label for="checkout">Check out date</label>

          <input name="checkout" type="text" id="checkout"  placeholder="click to enter" readonly required>
          </p>
        <p>         
          <label for="beds">Hotel type</label>
          <label for="hotel_type"></label>
          <select name="hotel_type" id="hotel_type">
            <option value="1" selected>1 star</option>
            <option value="2">2 star</option>
            <option value="3">3 star</option>
            <option value="4">4 star</option>
            <option value="5">5 star</option>
          </select>
          <input type="submit" name="search_button" id="search_button" value="Search">
        </p>
      </form>
```

required validation is not working. I am entering the dates using a jquery calendar. that is why  I disabled text edit by giving read only. Is there any problem with readonly?

Comment: read-only and required are two opposite sides!

Comment: I added readonly to protect the format of date from manual entry . I wanted to make sure it is entered also . thanks

Comment: remove readonly and validate input.you can use datepicker

Comment: Entering a date requires the field to change the value, a read-only permission is there to prohibit the value change, no modifications are allowed.

Comment: Perhaps you can use jQuery to prevent the user from input.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: solved using input type= "date". thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the concern.The problem is solved by using  the input type date . It gives a calendar to pick date and cannot misformat the date also